# Shared Variables in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

So I took an OS class last semester and we had a concurrency/threading project. It was an airport sim that landed planes / had them take off into the direction that the wind was blowing. We had to do it in Java. So now that finals are over and I'm bored, I'm trying to do it in C++11. In Java I used a synchronized variable for the wind (0 - 360) in main and passed it to the 3 threads I was using. My question is: Can you do that in C++11? It's a basic reader/writer, one thread writes/updates the wind, the other 2 (takeoff/land) read.

I got it working by having a global wind variable in my "threads.cpp" implementation file. But is there a way to pass a variable to as many threads as I want and all of them keep up with it? Or is it actually better for me to just use the global variable and not pass anything?(why/why not?) I was looking at `std::ref()` but that didn't work.

EDIT: I'm already using mutex and lock_guard. I'm just trying to figure out how to pass and keep a variable up to date in all threads. Right now it only updates in the write thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `std::mutex` with `std::lock_guard` to synchronize access to the shared data.  Or if the shared data fits in an integer, you can use `std::atomic<int>` without locking.

If you want to avoid global variables, simply pass the address of the shared state to the thread functions when you launch them.  For example:

```
void thread_entry1(std::atomic<int>* val) {}
void thread_entry2(std::atomic<int>* val) {}

std::atomic<int> shared_value;
std::thread t1(thread_entry1, &shared_value);
std::thread t2(thread_entry2, &shared_value);
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I was trying to do! It almost seems like it's more of a pain then just using the global var though. Is there any +/- for doing it this way?

Comment: Well, most people consider global variables to be poor practice most of the time.  Makes testing harder, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` mimicks what a Java synchronized variable does (only in Java this happens secretly without you knowing, in C++ you do it explicitly).

However, having **one** producer (there is just one direction of wind) and otherwise only consumers, it suffices to write to a e.g. `std::atomic<int>` variable with relaxed ordering, and to read from that variable from each consumer, again with relaxed ordering. Unless you have the requirement that the global view of all airplanes are consistent (but then you would have to run a lockstep simulation, which makes threading nonsensical), there is no need for synchronization, you only have to make sure that any value that any airplane reads at any time is eventually correct and that no garbled intermediate results can occur. In other words, you need an atomic update.
Relaxed memory ordering is sufficient too, since if all you read is one value, you do not need any happens-before guarantees.

An atomic update (or rather, atomic write) is at least an order of magnitude, if not more, faster. Atomic reads and writes with relaxed ordering are indeed plain normal reads and writes on many (most) mainstream architectures.

The variable needs not be global, you can as well keep it in the main thread's simultion loop's scope and pass a reference (or pointer) to the threads.

Comment: huh. Sounds like atomic is more appropriate for my problem than mutex/lock_guard. What I was doing, because I was looking at the Java code I wrote already, was passing by value instead of by reference. I should prob. use atomic for the wind and the mutex/lock_guard for the runways. Thank's for the help!

Comment: Mutex for runway certainly makes sense since only one plane can be on a runway at a time (without things getting nasty). Only for sampling the current wind direction doesn't really need mutex.

Comment: Using a std::atomic<int> certainly works, but this is premature optimization. As there are multiple variables (runway, wind, ...) a mutex for guarding the whole state is the first thing to have in mind.

Comment: Also, use of relaxed ordering is correct, but this is overkill premature optimization. You generally don't want to use these rather than the default strongest ordering until you have proved that this is the bottleneck. I've seen several shit hitting the fan because of unneeded (and wrong) ordering tweaking. I would not give that kind of advice to a beginner asking a more basic question...

Comment: @galinette: No, definitively no. First, there is only one shared variable -- runways are constants. Thus, while a mutex will work, it _may_ be unnecessary. Second, memory ordering is not an optimization, it is about correctness and about understanding the implications. If one does not understant the implications of memory ordering, then one should not use threads at all. Relaxed ordering is _correct_ for wind direction since there are no dependenceis whatsoever. Sure enough sequential consistency will _work_, but it is an (incorrect) pessimization, as would acquire/release be. In fact, from...

Comment: ... from a correctness point of view, they are wrong. If you write e.g. some other unrelated (not shared) state here and then, and follow with a release/acquire, then what you are saying is _"this must happen and be globally visible before the wind direction changes"_. Which is just nonsensical since the wind doesn't care, and whatevre happens e.g. inside a cockpit or inside the tower happens either _in reaction to_, or _independently_ of the wind changing direction. Never the other way around, so assuming a happens-before relation is formally wrong (although it "works").

Comment: Many languages have threads but no ordering notion, c++ being an exception. You are missing the whole point of premature optimization.

Comment: See for instance the conclusion of this article : https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/23/the-inscrutable-c-memory-model/
If Bartosz Milewski thinks this, I would personally feel very presumptuous thinking I can optmize all atomics memory ordering at every use.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create say, the wind object, on the heap with `new` through an `std::shared_ptr`.  Pass this pointer to all interested threads and use a `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` to change it.

Comment: Thanks. I have to check out shared_ptr. I'm just making the change from c++98 to 11, should be a fun winter break!

Comment: You're also making the change from Java to C++ and this is a pivot point you need to get your head around.  In Java objects are automatically created on the heap and memory managed for you.  In C++ you have to take on this responsibility yourself.   But there are some great C++11 (and C++14!) standard library helpers you need to get to grips with to make this journey as sweet as possible..  Welcome to C++ land have a great winter break! :) )